# Composite ID identity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Database table has 2-columns PK - `(ID, ClientID)` where `ClientID` is a FK, `ID` column is set up as *identity*. Fluent NH mapping of this entity:

```
CompositeId(x => x.Id)
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ID")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ClientId, "ClientID");
```

On trying to insert new row NH tells `Invalid index 10 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=10.` As I understood it tries to insert `ID` value too but as it is configured as identity there is no need to insert `ID`.
Is it possible to configure `.KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ID")` mapping as identity like we can do with *non-composite id*?

Comment: A long as `ClientId` is *FK*, try to replace `.KeyProperty(x => x.ClientId, "ClientID")` with `.KeyReference(x => x.ClientId, "ClientID")`

Answer (score 0):

Identity columns as part of composite keys are not supported. But you shouldn't need them either: the identity column is unique by itself.